# ThinkTecture IdentityServer Authorize Directory

Tags: asp.net-identity, federated-identity, thinktecture-ident-server

I am attempting to use [Thinktecture Identity Server v2](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2) as a federated identity manager. I have the identity server up and running and authentication works fine. My issue is that my test site I am using to test the authentication redirects to the identity server on page load at `localhost:8080/`, but what I would like to happen is the authentication redirect happen after a user clicks a link and only protect certain directories such as `localhost:8080/app/` and `localhost:8080/` should be accessible by non-authorized users. I essentially followed [this](http://vimeo.com/51666380) tutorial to set up the IdP.

My web.config currently contains

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ida:FederationMetadataLocation" value="https://localhost/idsrv/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml" />
    <add key="ida:Realm" value="https://localhost:8080/" />
    <add key="ida:AudienceUri" value="http://localhost/" />
<appSettings>
...
<system.identityModel.services>
    <federationConfiguration>
        <cookieHandler requireSsl="true" />
        <wsFederation
            passiveRedirectEnabled="true"
            issuer="https://localhost/idsrv/issue/wsfed"
            realm="http://localhost/"
            requireHttps="true" />
    </federationConfiguration>
</system.identityModel.services>
```

I have attempted to change the realm using

```
<add key="ida:Realm" value="https://localhost:8080/app/" />
```

but the redirect still happens when I land on `localhost:8080/` instead of where I want it to happen at `localhost:8080/app/`.

**EDIT**: I guess what I am really asking here is what is a Realm and what is AudienceUri and how can I configure those to only protect certain sections (directories) of my app.

Answer (score 0):

The realm is the unique identifier of the application.  This can be any string at all.  I try to use something like urn-ApplicationName or something like that.  That way it is not tied to an arbitrary thing that iisexpress assigned to it and it actually has meaning.

AudienceUri is the list of uris that can be used to represent the relying party.

I believe what you want is actually a setting in Thinktecture.  There is a "Redirect Url" setting in the Relying parties maintenance page.  Set that to where you want it to redirect you to.